# My apps don't move to SD-card

Tags: sd-card, app2sd

I need some help.  I just bought a new phone Android 6.0 (Huawei Honor 7 lite)  and I can't move apps to my SD-card. I enabled primary storage as SD-card but the apps are still in internal memory and I can't seem to find option to move them to SD-card so I could really use some help if anybody knows how to move apps.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help.

*Source: Tomsguide*

Move Apps to SD Card Using **Application Manager** . So, you must install Application Manager first

1. Navigate to settings on your phone.You can find the settings menu in the app drawer.
2. Tap Application Manager.
3. Select an app you want to move to the microSD card.
4. Tap the Move to SD Card button. If you don't see a Move to SD Card button, the app cannot be moved. Most preloaded apps cannot be moved to an SD card. If you don't see Move to SD Card buttons on any apps, your device may not support this feature at all.

If you wish to move an app back to the internal memory, hit the "Move to device storage" button.

Comment: I already tried with app manager it shows me all the apps that can be moved to SD and it takes me to where i should be able to move the app to the SD card but there is no option "move to" at all. And as I said my primary storage is set as SD-card.